# Django - Modify query based on user logged in

Tags: sql, django

I have a database that has two tables: 'installs' and 'installers'. The 'install' table has a field for the installer. I would like the installer to be able to log in and see a list of only their installs.

For now, I am working with SQLite but will use MySQL for production.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Install(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank = True, null = True)
    phone= models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=90, blank = True, null = True)
    unit_model = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_installer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_dealer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    unit_distributor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    install_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self): # unicode in python 2
        return self.name 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('installs:install_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Installer(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    installer_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=60, blank = True, null = True)
    phone= models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=90, blank = True, null = True)
    trained_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self): # unicode in python 2
        return self.name # what should this be???

    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('installers:installer_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

And views.py (installers not completed):

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.forms import ModelForm, forms
#from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget
from bdb.models import Install, models

class InstallForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Install
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'email', 'phone', 'unit_model', 'unit_discharge',
        'gpd', 'ptgals', 'rgals', 'serial', 'unit_installer', 'unit_dealer', 'unit_distributor', 'install_date']


class InstallerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Installer
        fields =['name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zipcode', 'email', 'phone', 'website', 'installerID', 'trainedBy']

def install_list(request, template_name='installs/installs_list.html'):
    install = Install.objects.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = install
    return render(request, template_name, data)

def install_create(request, template_name='installs/installs_form.html'):
    form = InstallForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('installs:install_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})

def install_update(request, pk, template_name='installs/installs_form.html'):
    cust = get_object_or_404(Install, pk=pk)
    form = InstallForm(request.POST or None, instance=cust)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('installs:installs_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})

def install_delete(request, pk, template_name='installs/installs_confirm_delete.html'):
    cust = get_object_or_404(Install, pk=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        cust.delete()
        return redirect('installs:installs_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'object':cust})
```

edit: added models.py and views.py

Comment: Please add code for `models` and `views`.

Comment: I added them. I didn't complete the installers in views.py.

Comment: How are the 2 models related to each other? Couldn't find a relation between them.

Comment: I didn't add that in yet. The unit_installer will be a one to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct to assume that your `Installer` model is some sort of profile-like model for your `User` model?

If so, and once you have the relation between `Install` and `Installer`, things are much easier, if for example you defined the relation like:

```
class Install(models.Model):
    installer = models.ForeignKey('Installer', related_name='installs')
```

as you could simply do in your view:

```
def install_list(request, template_name='installs/installs_list.html'):
    installs = request.user.installer.installs.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = install
    return render(request, template_name, data)
```

Comment: That looks pretty simple. I would imagine I need the @login_required before the view, correct?

Comment: if the assumption I asked in the first sentence is true, then yes. otherwise you can fetch the appropriate `Installer` (up to you how to implement that) and get their `Install`s by `installer.installs.all()`